# Python FPDF print table with header and index, rotate header

Tags: python, dataframe, pyfpdf

I have a dataframe table. I want to save it in a PDF page. The table has lengthy column names, when I print it, table goes outside the margin and data misses. Also, I cannot see the row index printed here:

My data:

```
prdf=

group   FF_ThisWeek FF_ThreeMonths  ifrac_ThisWeek  ifrac_ThreeMonths   vfrac_ThisWeek  vfrac_ThreeMonths
6.A-3.2.10  0.75    0.76    0.90    0.90    0.84    0.84
6.A-3.2.11  0.71    0.70    0.85    0.83    0.83    0.85
6.A-3.2.12  0.77    0.76    0.92    0.91    0.84    0.84
6.A-3.2.2   0.75    0.76    0.93    0.92    0.81    0.83
6.A-3.2.4   0.74    0.75    0.91    0.91    0.81    0.83
6.A-3.2.5   0.75    0.76    0.90    0.90    0.84    0.85
6.A-3.2.6   0.75    0.76    0.92    0.91    0.82    0.83
6.A-3.2.8   0.76    0.75    0.92    0.90    0.82    0.83

# code
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf=FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('arial', 'B', 11)
### Where to start on the page, x-position
pdf.cell(60)
pdf.cell(75, 10,"Table: FF, Vmpp/Voc,Impp/Ioc in this week and last three months", 0, 2, 'C')
pdf.cell(90, 5, '', 0, 2, 'C')
pdf.cell(-55)
columnNameList = list(prdf.columns)
for header in columnNameList[:-1]:  
  pdf.cell(35,10, header, 1, 0, 'L')
pdf.cell(35, 10, columnNameList[-1], 1, 2, 'C')
pdf.cell(-140)
pdf.set_font('arial', '', 11)
for row in range(0, len(prdf)):
  for col_num, col_name in enumerate(columnNameList):
      # print(df['%s' % (col_name)].iloc[row])
    if col_num != len(columnNameList) - 1:
      pdf.cell(35, 10, str(prdf['%s' % (col_name)].iloc[row]), 1, 0, 'C')
    else:
      pdf.cell(35, 10, str(prdf['%s' % (col_name)].iloc[row]), 1, 2, 'C')
      pdf.cell(-140)
pdf.cell(35, 10, "", 0, 2)
pdf.cell(20)
# pdf.image('iris_grouped_df.png', x = None, y = None, w = 0, h = 0, type = '', link = '')
pdf.output(pdf_name2, 'F')
```

Present output:

[image]